# Print multiple QTextDocuments with QPrinter

Tags: c++, qt, qtextdocument, qprinter

I need to generate a document to print for a number of objects which the user creates dynamically, and I want to print these documents. I wrote following code (generateDocument() takes a reference to the document to add html code):

```
QPrinter printer;
QPrintDialog popup(&printer);
if (popup.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _quiz->getSerieCount(); i++)
    {
        QTextDocument doc;
        generateDocument(doc, _quiz->getSerie(i));
        doc.print(&printer);
    }
}
```

When printing to pdf the behaviour is different in linux and windows: On linux this just prints the last generated document, and on windows it prompts to select a new pdf for every generateDocument() call.

Am i supposed to do this differently?

Comment: Why do you need a new QTextDocument for each getSerie? Have you tried adding all HTML to a single QTextDocument?

Comment: Can I force to start a new page in html? It is required that each serie is printed on a different page...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a page break for each serie and then print the document.
Try with the following e.g.

```
QTextDocument doc;
QTextCursor cursor(&doc);

for (int i = 0; i < _quiz->getSerieCount(); i++)
{
    if(i!=0) \\ dont add page break for the first document
    {
        QTextBlockFormat blockFormat;
        blockFormat.setPageBreakPolicy(QTextFormat::PageBreak_AlwaysAfter);
        cursor.insertBlock(blockFormat);
    }

    // < append _quiz->getSerie(i) contents in the document >    
}

doc.print(&printer);
```

Haven't tested the code, but should work on Windows without any problems I suppose, because I was using it similarly without any issues. Can't comment anything for its behavior on Linux machines. You can modify it better to suit your need.
Hope this Helps.

Comment: we can use page breaks for seperating pages, what about displaying each page in a different qtextedit or on some other widget for example?